# Derivation of the transfer function for an inverter-grid interface filter

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function

I am reading a paper in which the filter interface between an inverter and grid is studied (figure 1)
[image: figure 1]

The paper started by giving the transfer function between the inverter's output voltage (V<sub>br</sub>) as follows:
[image]

I tried derive the same transfer function and this is what i got, it came to my attention that the only difference is in my Thevenin voltage.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

what went wrong with my derivation?

---

Figures and equations are retrieved from "Output Filter Design for a Grid-interconnected Three-phase Inverter" by Timothy CY Wang, Zhihong Ye, Gautam Sinha, Xiaoming Yuan

Comment: Surely that opening formula (from the paper) must depend on \$V_g\$ or assumptions about it.

Comment: Please cite the paper the figure was obtained from.

Comment: @TimWilliams , the question is amended with reference to the paper

Comment: @Andyaka I assure you that I hold no ill intentions. I am doubting myself and my skills, not the paper. I will remove my comment to you to avoid any misunderstanding.

Comment: In your first step you show ZL1 || ZC, which directly gives the imaginary zero in the result. Can you explain this premise?

Comment: @TimWilliams I got the thevinin equivalent circuit at the node from V_br. to the the node before (L_g).

Comment: Right, that's Zth looking left into Vc, well, plus L2. But that doesn't get you Vbr. But you have Vbr/(s^2+1) stuff later. You just forgot to cancel?

Comment: @TimWilliams I did forget to cancel, my mistake. Apologies. and Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It seems you forgot to cancel the highlighted term (blue parentheses).  Your arithmetic seems generally correct otherwise.

It should be stated for posterity that three-phase seems to be assumed, i.e. the common mode between output/mains lines can be ignored, and any "virtual" neutral points can be treated as ground (so, the wye common of C, etc.).  Also that the damping network is ignored, which, I'm guessing simply is being ignored at this stage.  Hence the lack of damping (s^1) term in the equivalent impedance.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain this transfer function using the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs. Doing so, you determine the transadmittance transfer function painlessly through a few sketches, without writing a single line of algebra:

[image]

You first start with \$s=0\$ which is a dc condition where the inductors are shorted and the capacitor is open. Then, you reduce the stimulus to 0 V (short the input voltage source) and you determine the time constants of the circuit by "looking" for the resistance \$R\$ offered by each energy-storing element when temporarily disconnected from the circuit.

When all the time constants are assembled, you obtain a *low-entropy* expression in which the leading term is of the same dimension than that of the transfer function. Then, the next step is to factor this 3rd-order polynomial into the product of a pole and a 2nd-order expression to unveil a resonant frequency with a quality factor. This is to let you calculate the components values so that the filter provides the required attenuation at the selected frequency.

Needless to say that this is an over-simplified filter and parasitics like the equivalent series resistances of the capacitor - \$r_C\$ - and the inductor - \$r_L\$ - will affect the transfer function big time. For instance, FACTs tell you that adding a resistance in series with the capacitor will introduce a zero in the transfer function.

More on FACTs in my [APEC 2016](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf) seminar.